# Fastest way to find duplicate number in large list

Tags: ruby, algorithm, duplicates

I am dealing with a large list (order of 10^5) of Ids (which are long data type). I have to find the duplicates in the list of Id's. But I am restricted to use ruby.

Here I have found a way to do this.
I will traverse the list and put the Id in hash but before putting in to hash, I will check that it is already in hash or not.

I am not sure about the complexity of the hash in RUBY.

Please suggest me a better idea.

Comment: Your idea sounds good. Is it actually slow? Please share your results.

Comment: What makes you think that the complexity of hashes in Ruby would be different from other languages? Hashing is generally considered to take O(1) time as long as the load factor is not too close to 1.

Comment: One approach is to try to get the list sorted and then iterate over it in chunks of 2: x.sort.each_cons(2).select{|x, y| x == y}.map(&:first).uniq

Answer (score 5):

Why don't you use `Set`?

```
require 'set'

set = Set.new
numbers.each do |number|
  puts "Number #{number} is already in the set" unless set.add?(number)
end
```

Or simply finding the duplicates:

```
require 'set'
set = Set.new
duplicates = numbers.reject { |number| set.add?(number) }
```

Comment: Good solution. Note that this is equivalent to what the original poster is suggesting (using a `Hash`). Solution is `O(n)`.

Comment: Yeah, it's almost the same except it may use less memory (implementation dependent).

Comment: In theory yes, but in practice, is there any implementation that doesn't use a `Hash` to handle `Set`?

Comment: Maybe right now there aren't any but this could be changed in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Let's see what [Benchmark](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html) says:

```
require 'benchmark'
require 'set'


def rand_n(n, max)
  randoms = Array.new
  loop do
    randoms << rand(max)
    return randoms.to_a if randoms.size >= n
  end
end

numbers = rand_n(10000, 10000000)

counter = Hash.new
time = Benchmark.measure do
  for number in numbers
    if counter.has_key?(number)
      counter[number] = counter[number]+1
    else
      counter[number]=1
    end
  end
duplicates = counter.select{|k,v| v > 1}
end
puts time

time1 = Benchmark.measure do
  counts = Hash.new{|h,k| h[k] = 0 }
  numbers.each{|n| counts[n] +=1}
  duplicates = counts.select{|k,v| v > 1}
end
puts time1

set = Set.new
time2 = Benchmark.measure do
  duplicates = numbers.reject { |number| set.add?(number) }
end

puts time2
```

And the output:

```
  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.006114)
  0.010000   0.000000   0.010000 (  0.008529)
  0.010000   0.000000   0.010000 (  0.006098)
```

**EDIT:** Updated with the duplicate finding within the benchmark and updated the results.

Comment: Your implementation lacks of collecting the duplicates.

Comment: @KARASZIIstván Check all the code... there are three methods resulting in three diferent benchmarks. The last one is equal to your solution.

Comment: I checked your code that's why I wrote my comment. You created a Hash with the counters but you need to get the duplicates from those hash and that is missing from your benchmark.

Comment: @KARASZIIstván I've updated the code in the example. Thanks for pointing it.

Comment: But you need to put that part into the benchmarked block because that needs to be included in the numbers as well, without that you're comparing peaches to apples.

Comment: Sure would be nice if you used `Benchmark`'s labeling capability to tell us what the numbers correspond to.